# Ionic 3 jQuery-snapPuzzle plugin

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm doing a mobile application with Ionic 3. I need to use jquery plugin. The plugin's name is jQuery-snapPuzzle.

I called jquery, jquery-ui and snap-js js files in src / index.html.

Then in the "typescript" file of the page where this plugin will work
`import * as $ from "jquery";` I've written.

and I added the following codes in the ionViewDidLoad section;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('img.puzzle').snapPuzzle({ rows: 3, columns: 3 });
});
```

I get the following error when I run it.

"ERROR TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_jquery**(...).snapPuzzle is not a function" --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2seo.png

After getting this error, I added the above code between index.html  . This time it doesn't fail, but it doesn't work as if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

instead

```
declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;
```

my problem improved.